# Is my hardware compatible with Ubuntu (& its flavors)?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, hardware, compatibility

I heard that linux doesn't work well with Nvidia GPUs. That's why I'm concerned about the switch from Windows to `Ubuntu`. Because Windows works with latest hardware pretty much every time because it has a larger market share. But I want to switch to `Ubuntu`. (Maybe even `Kubuntu`)

Is my hardware fully compatible with Ubuntu (and it's other flavors)?

My Hardware is:

- Intel Core i3-8100 3.6 GHz
- Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650 (4 GB)
- 8 GB DDR4 2400 MHz RAM
- AsROCK H310CM HDV/M.2 Motherboard
- 250 GB NVMe M.2 SSD

Comment: Nothing is too new, so it should be. It is easy to run Ubuntu from USB without installing, and test all the hardware. Why don't you try, and let us know how it went.

Comment: Okay, sure will do. But I'm actually also concerned about the performance of Ubuntu on my hardware. In live disk I can't see the performance. Will Ubuntu run slow on my PC because of Nvidia Gpu? @mikewhatever

Comment: Kubuntu requires less resource than Ubuntu (also, Kubuntu's interface resembles that of Windows more than Ubuntu deos). However, this hardware is good enough for regular Ubuntu.

Comment: @Archishman Panigrahi I can't install Kubuntu, it won't go past the Motherboard logo after saying "Restart" after the live disk installation.

Comment: Did you install the restricted proprietary drivers as part of the install. That way you get the correct nVidia driver for your system. Now you have to manually install it by booting with nomodeset. But that is a separate question and answered many times. One of them: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it